# how come some statements require the return statement at the end of some groovy closures?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def handleLogin = {
   def hashPassd = DU.md5Hex(params.password)
   // Find the username
   def user = User.findByUserNameAndPassword(params.userName, hashPassd)
   if (!user) {
      flash.message = "User not found for userName: ${params.userName}"
      redirect(action:'index')
      return
   } else {
      session.user = user
      redirect(controller:'todo')
   }
}
```

how come the if condition requires the return statement? and the else block don't require it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the return is not necessary. If the return isn't there it will continue to after the if, which is the end of the method, and thus returns.

Comment: You would use an explicit `return` if you wanted to return a value from the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The return is not strictly necessary but it's a good habit to get into.  Calls like `render` and `redirect` in a controller action are usually intended to be the conceptual "end" of the action, and its easy to forget sometimes and treat the redirect as if it were a `return`

```
def someAction() {
  if(!params.id) {
    flash.message = "no ID provided"
    redirect action:'error'
  }

  def myObj = MyObj.get(params.id)
  //...
}
```

This will fail at runtime, probably with a rather obscure error message, and to avoid this possibility it's a good idea to remember to put an explicit `return` after any calls to `redirect` or `render`.  It's the kind of thing that has bitten me when coming back to make changes to a controller action I originally wrote 6 months previously...